# Tomcat6 Manager Webapp is 404 on apt-get install on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: configuration, tomcat6, ubuntu-10.10

http://localhost:8080/manager/html gives a 404 error on apt-get install of tomcat6 (6.0.28 on JVM 1.6.0_20-b20 on 2.6.35-27-generic amd64).

http://localhost:8080/host-manager/html works. Lists one Host name, localhost.

Installed tomcat6-admin with apt-get.

`$ ls dpkg -l | grep -i tomcat6-admin`

`ii  tomcat6-admin                        6.0.28-2ubuntu1.1                                 Servlet and JSP engine -- admin web applications`

`$ cat /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

`<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager" />
<user username="tomcatuser" password="Password1" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>`

`$ cat /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml`

`<Context path="/manager"

    docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6-admin/manager"

    antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />

<role name="manager" />

<user name="manager" password="Password1" roles="manager" />

<user name="tomcatuser" password="Password1" roles="manager" />`

Those two files are the only documentation I've seen on how to setup the Manager webapp, and they seem to be compliant with the requirements.

However, the Tomcat XML parser doesn't seem to like that first tag in manager.xml:
`Mar 18, 2011 2:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pursing the error log message from `catalina.out`, finally realized that I got confused when copy-pasting and put the `<role>` and `<user>` tags in both `tomcat-users.xml` and `manager.xml`. Those tags can only go in `tomcat-users.xml`. Once the tags were removed from `manager.xml`, the Manager began working.

To restate, the only contents of `manager.xml` are

```
<Context path="/manager"
docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6-admin/manager"
antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />
```

Would be nice to

1. Have better error message in the parser
2. Require the manager.xml to be well-formed
3. not have the Manager serve a 404 error when a deployment fails.

Comment: Great, I'm been all over trying to solve this on my MintLinux 11 machine.

Answer (score 0):

The manager webapp isn't installed by default; have you run `apt-get install tomcat6-admin`?

Comment: Good question, sadly yes. Added clarification info to question.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that your tomcat service is stuck in the background.  Kill all stuck tomcat processes to make absolutely sure that your reconfiguration is being picked up.